# Gentoo service takes too long to start and init system gives up

Tags: mysql, daemon, gentoo, init.d

At some points in my gentoo system mysqld daemon would take too much time to start.
When system boots up, gentoo timeouts and thinks that the daemon has not started, however it starts eventually in background.
But gentoo still thinks that it is not started.
What can be done in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give us as much information as possible, so that we have it easier to help you. Thanks

Comment: I belive this question would fit better on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following values in your `/etc/conf.d/mysql`:

```
# This setting (in seconds) should be high enough to allow InnoDB to do a full
# checkpoint recovery. 900 is the default used in the upstream RPM startup
# scripts. 30 seconds should be sufficent if you just have a tiny <1GiB
# database. After the core startup is done, we wait this long for the UNIX
# socket to appear.
STARTUP_TIMEOUT="900"

# This is how long, in milliseconds, we wait for pidfile to be created, early
# in the startup.
STARTUP_EARLY_TIMEOUT="1000"
```